# Why my character won't jump with my code?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I have this problem with my 2D game project,I pasted and modified it a little bit from the code can be found in this video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwcT-Dch0bA
But the problem is it won't jump I added Debug.Log to see if the input is really the reason why my character won't jump,I tested it and it won't jump but it still shows me that the "q" button is pressed.I tried with another way is that changing input in unity but it just doesn't work.I used the same code in Brackeys's project and it works like normal.
Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public CharacterController2D controller;

    public float runSpeed = 40f;
    float horizontalMove = 0f;
    bool jump = false;
    bool crouch = false;

    void Update()
    {

        horizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * runSpeed;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("q"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Jump button works");
            jump = true;
            
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Crouch"))
        {
            crouch = true;
        }
        else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Crouch"))
        {
            crouch = false;
        }

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        controller.Move(horizontalMove * Time.fixedDeltaTime, crouch, jump);
        jump = true;
    }
}
```

CharacterController2D:

```
public class CharacterController2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float m_JumpForce = 400f;                          // Amount of force added when the player jumps.
    [Range(0, 1)] [SerializeField] private float m_CrouchSpeed = .36f;          // Amount of maxSpeed applied to crouching movement. 1 = 100%
    [Range(0, .3f)] [SerializeField] private float m_MovementSmoothing = .05f;  // How much to smooth out the movement
    [SerializeField] private bool m_AirControl = false;                         // Whether or not a player can steer while jumping;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask m_WhatIsGround;                          // A mask determining what is ground to the character
    [SerializeField] private Transform m_GroundCheck;                           // A position marking where to check if the player is grounded.
    [SerializeField] private Transform m_CeilingCheck;                          // A position marking where to check for ceilings
    [SerializeField] private Collider2D m_CrouchDisableCollider;                // A collider that will be disabled when crouching

    const float k_GroundedRadius = .2f; // Radius of the overlap circle to determine if grounded
    private bool m_Grounded;            // Whether or not the player is grounded.
    const float k_CeilingRadius = .2f; // Radius of the overlap circle to determine if the player can stand up
    private Rigidbody2D m_Rigidbody2D;
    private bool m_FacingRight = true;  // For determining which way the player is currently facing.
    private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

    private void Awake()
    {
        m_Rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }


    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        m_Grounded = false;

        // The player is grounded if a circlecast to the groundcheck position hits anything designated as ground
        // This can be done using layers instead but Sample Assets will not overwrite your project settings.
        Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(m_GroundCheck.position, k_GroundedRadius, m_WhatIsGround);
        for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++)
        {
            if (colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject)
                m_Grounded = true;
        }
    }


    public void Move(float move, bool crouch, bool jump)
    {
        // If crouching, check to see if the character can stand up
        if (!crouch)
        {
            // If the character has a ceiling preventing them from standing up, keep them crouching
            if (Physics2D.OverlapCircle(m_CeilingCheck.position, k_CeilingRadius, m_WhatIsGround))
            {
                crouch = true;
            }
        }

        //only control the player if grounded or airControl is turned on
        if (m_Grounded || m_AirControl)
        {

            // If crouching
            if (crouch)
            {
                // Reduce the speed by the crouchSpeed multiplier
                move *= m_CrouchSpeed;

                // Disable one of the colliders when crouching
                if (m_CrouchDisableCollider != null)
                    m_CrouchDisableCollider.enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                // Enable the collider when not crouching
                if (m_CrouchDisableCollider != null)
                    m_CrouchDisableCollider.enabled = true;
            }

            // Move the character by finding the target velocity
            Vector3 targetVelocity = new Vector2(move * 10f, m_Rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
            // And then smoothing it out and applying it to the character
            m_Rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector3.SmoothDamp(m_Rigidbody2D.velocity, targetVelocity, ref velocity, m_MovementSmoothing);

            // If the input is moving the player right and the player is facing left...
            if (move > 0 && !m_FacingRight)
            {
                // ... flip the player.
                Flip();
            }
            // Otherwise if the input is moving the player left and the player is facing right...
            else if (move < 0 && m_FacingRight)
            {
                // ... flip the player.
                Flip();
            }
        }
        // If the player should jump...
        if (m_Grounded && jump)
        {
            // Add a vertical force to the player.
            m_Grounded = false;
            m_Rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, m_JumpForce));
        }
    }


    private void Flip()
    {
        // Switch the way the player is labelled as facing.
        m_FacingRight = !m_FacingRight;

        // Multiply the player's x local scale by -1.
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;
    }
}
```

Comment: We need the method Move in the CharacterController2D class. Edit your question with that code please.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code is not very optimized.
You call Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll () every frame and it's not very good for performance.
As an alternative you can use [Physics2D.OverlapCircleNonAlloc()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircleNonAlloc.html), which will save some memory, or even better, use OnCollisionEnter2D () and OnCollisionExit2D () to understand when it collides with something.
Speaking of the scripts, they seem to have to work. Try adding a print(m_Grounded + “ " + jump) and say what appears in the console.
When you press q both should be true, but apparently one of them isn't, and with that print() we'll find out what it is and fix the problem.

```
public void Move(float move, bool crouch, bool jump)
{
    // If crouching, check to see if the character can stand up
    if (!crouch)
    {
        // If the character has a ceiling preventing them from standing up, keep them crouching
        if (Physics2D.OverlapCircle(m_CeilingCheck.position, k_CeilingRadius, m_WhatIsGround))
        {
            crouch = true;
        }
    }

    //only control the player if grounded or airControl is turned on
    if (m_Grounded || m_AirControl)
    {

        // If crouching
        if (crouch)
        {
            // Reduce the speed by the crouchSpeed multiplier
            move *= m_CrouchSpeed;

            // Disable one of the colliders when crouching
            if (m_CrouchDisableCollider != null)
                m_CrouchDisableCollider.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Enable the collider when not crouching
            if (m_CrouchDisableCollider != null)
                m_CrouchDisableCollider.enabled = true;
        }

        // Move the character by finding the target velocity
        Vector3 targetVelocity = new Vector2(move * 10f, m_Rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
        // And then smoothing it out and applying it to the character
        m_Rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector3.SmoothDamp(m_Rigidbody2D.velocity, targetVelocity, ref velocity, m_MovementSmoothing);

        // If the input is moving the player right and the player is facing left...
        if (move > 0 && !m_FacingRight)
        {
            // ... flip the player.
            Flip();
        }
        // Otherwise if the input is moving the player left and the player is facing right...
        else if (move < 0 && m_FacingRight)
        {
            // ... flip the player.
            Flip();
        }
    }
    // If the player should jump…
    print(“m_Grounded = " + m_Grounded + " && jump = " + jump);
    if (m_Grounded && jump)
    {
        // Add a vertical force to the player.
        m_Grounded = false;
        m_Rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, m_JumpForce));
    }
}
```

**if you think my answer helped you, you can mark it as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) and vote positively. I would very much appreciate it :)**

Comment: Thanks for answering but I have a problem running the codes 
I can't really find a solution to fix the: The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item at (1,1)
Can you help me?
I'm still new to Unity so I don't have much knowledge on this yet.

Comment: Replace your Move () method with mine that I wrote in the answer. The rest of the script must remain unchanged.